# How can I extract vector from filtered data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I extract value from filtered data frame ?

For example let's take 100 hundred longest flights in flights data set.

```
library(dplyr)
data(flights)<-data(flights) 
flights %>%
  slice_max(order_by=arr_time, n=100)
```

And I want to extract distance vector. So why I did is :

```
df<-flights %>%
      slice_max(order_by=arr_time, n=100)

vec<-df['distance']

#Problem

length(vec)
150
```

So my question is : why the length is 150 and not 100 ?

Comment: Use argument `with_ties` = F to take first 100 values.

Answer (score 0):

`max` value in `arr_time` is 2400

```
max(flights$arr_time, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2400
```

There are total 150 rows in `flights` which has that value.

```
sum(flights$arr_time == max(flights$arr_time, na.rm = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 150
```

`slice_max` keeps all the rows in case of a tie hence all the rows are selected which has value 2400. If you want exact 100 rows `arrange` the data and then `slice` to select first 100 rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(desc(arr_time)) %>% slice(1:100)
```